# Documents store database and connected domain

Tags: mongodb, document-store

Consider this picture:

[image: Documents store, denormalized model]

The book says documents store database struggle with highly connected domains because *"relationships between aggregates aren’t firstclass citizens in the data model, most aggregate stores furnish only the insides of aggregates with structure, in the form of nested maps.
"*.

And besides: *"Instead, the application that uses the database must build relationships from these flat, disconnected data structures."*

I'm sorry, I don't understand what does it mean. Why documents store database struggle with a context based on highly relationships?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because document stores do not support joins. Each time you need to get more data it is a separate query. Instead, document stores support the idea of nesting data within documents.